# Counters and Lines Problem. Can someone please explain the approach to be followed for this problem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Question:
Problem Statement:
To enter Todo's amusement park, there are M counters. Total N people want to enter the amusement park, each of whom will line up in front of one of the counters. Any counter worker gets angry if the number of people lining up in front of him is at least 2 more than the number of people lining up in front of any of its neighboring counters. The worker at the K-th counter works the fastest.
Find the maximum number of people that can line up in front of the K-th counter such that each counter gets at least one person and no counter worker is angry.
Input
The input contains three integers M, N, and K.
Output: Print the maximum number of people that can line up in front of the Kth counter such that each counter gets at least one person and no counter worker is angry.
Test Cases:
Sample Input:
3 6 1

Sample Output:
3

Explanation: Optimal Arrangement is 3 2 1.

Comment: Add any approach you might have tried, along with the issue you're facing

Comment: I was thinking about finding all possible combinations of m numbers that sum to n. Then find the subset where (k-1)th element has the max value and return the max. This would take O(n^m) time though.

Comment: Let's say that M is 7, an K is 3, so there are 2 counters to the left of K, and 4 to the right. Start by putting one person at each counter, since the problem statement requires one person per counter. That uses 7 people. If there are people left over, you can add 1 person to counter K to increase the number of people at counter K to 2, and the distribution is 1,1,2,1,1,1,1. To increase the number the people at K to 3, you need three more people to get 1,2,3,2,1,1,1. Then you need to add 5 people to have 4 people at K. How many more people do you need to add to reach 5 people at K?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Binary Search Solution- I tried

```
ll get(ll m, ll k){
    ll d = k;
    if (k > m) d = m;
     k -= d;
    
    return k + d * (2 * m - d + 1) / 2;
}



signed main(){
    ll n, p, k; cin >> n >> p >> k;
    ll l = 1, r = p+1;
 
    while(l + 1 < r){
        ll m = (l + r) / 2;
         cout<<get(m, k) <<" "<<get(m, n - k + 1)<<" "<<m<<endl;
        if ( ull(get(m, k)) + get(m, n - k + 1) - m > p)
            r = m;
        else l = m;
    }
 
    cout << l << endl;
}
```